# Azuma's inequality conditional version

Tags: inequality, martingales

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Consider a  martingale $M_n$ with filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$. Let $B \in \mathcal{F}$. On $B$, $a_n \leq |M_n - M_{n-1}| \leq b_n$ a.s.
Can we find any concentration inequation for 
$$P(|M_n| \geq t | B)$$

if $B \in \mathcal{F}_1$, we can easily find such inequality. I am intersted in the case $B \notin \mathcal{F}_1$